# How to search loosely in pouch db

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Good day,

Im using pouch db to search for usernames in my database, only problem is its showing the user only if i write the name the way it was saved, **eg** if i search Mario instead of mario it wont show anything .

```
// run the search options
 const options={
            selector:{
                // user_id:{$eq:getUserInfo().Email}
                name:{$gte:value}
            },
    }


    Search_GetAll(organization_users_db,options).then(res=>{
        // console.log(res)
        setData(res.docs)
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Yep worked thanks!!!